# Selenium one driver and multiple tabs browser

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

When I use the codes below, the next tab replaces the first one:

```
ArrayList tabs = new ArrayList (driver.getWindowHandles());
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("body")).sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL +"t");
//driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("body")).sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL +"\t");
driver.switchTo().window((String) tabs.get(0));
driver.navigate().to("https://yahoo.com");


String currentTab = driver.getWindowHandle();
Robot r = new Robot();
r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL); 
r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_T); 
r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL); 
r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_T);    
ArrayList<String> tabs = new ArrayList<String>(driver.getWindowHandles());
    for (String tab : driver.getWindowHandles()) {
            driver.switchTo().window(tab);        
    }
driver.navigate().to("https://yahoo.com");
```

When I use a new driver, a new browser window opens for me. Is it possible to open the link in the next tab (not the same)? I tried different ways. A new window always opens up to me or the next tab is replaced with the previous one instead of opening another tab.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just view the link that opens up in the new tab, you can use `driver.switchTo().window();`.

But if you are thinking of running multiple threads in the same `WebDriver` object in the same browser window, then it is not possible.

I would rather suggest initiating multiple `WebDriver` instances which will spawn multiple browser windows.